# Bat file get date variable file name

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy

Every day many files are generated in directory on a user local computer, with this name structure:

```
8-05-21_09-05-2019_wolverine_WCALL1-010
hour_date_username_computername
```

The problem:
I need a batch file to run robocopy  to copy files generated only in actualy day. like this:

```
robocopy  09-05-2019 \\server\files\8-05-21_09-05-2019_wolverine_WCALL1-010
```

So, how can I get date in middle of file name?

Comment: Are you wanting to copy the file by actual created/modified date, or by the date in the name?

Comment: Read `robocopy /?` cite  `Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]`  And also on [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard by the date in the name

Comment: Since the date string is unique in the filename (it contains a string of 4 digits) then `robocopy  *09-05-2019* \\server\files\` would appear to be a candidate - but you haven't clearly specified where the date appears from, nor where the intended destination is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specifically work on the name only, here is one way.

```
@echo off
set day=0
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "yyyy=%result:~0,4%"
set "mm=%result:~4,2%"
set "dd=%result:~6,2%"
set "modD=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr "_%modD%"') do (
    robocopy "source" "destination" %%~i
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), you could select only files modified within the last 24 hours using the `/MaxAge` option with a value of `1`:

```bat
@RoboCopy "SourceDirectory" "DestinationDirectory" /MaxAge:1
```

If you need to [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) only files modified today, you may find it simpler to perform the task using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP "$d=$(Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd');RoboCopy "SourceDirectory" "DestinationDirectory" /MaxAge:$d"
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the date in a locale/user settings independent way (here with PowerShell)
Use wildcards around the date to select only files containing that date.

```
@Echo off
for /f %%A in ('powershell -NoP -c "get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy"') do set "dt=%%A"
RoboCopy "x:\sourcepath" "\\server\files" "*_%dt%_*"
```